# Android studio multiple Apk at once

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, apk

I have an application for 10 clients, for every client I need  to generate apk with one change in code:

```
setEnvironment(<ENUM CLASS>.<version>)
```

Is there a way to do it more universial? I need to have 10 separate apk, can  I build it at once?

Comment: //edit 
I do it with productFlavours for each version provide other variable in configField  and then switch do the rest job

Comment: You could use a configuration file e.g. placed in assets that contains the necessary data for each client. So in AndroidStudio you would have only one version and later use a script to replace the config file (using a ZIP tool) and re-sign the APK file.